# Expert Advisor is not showing any bug or warning, but doesn't work

Tags: mql4

I created an Expert Advisor that will open long and short positions based on some bands, there are the 1.6 band and 3.6 band, it sells at the 3.6 upper band, puts the tp at 1.6 lower band and sl at half the tp opposite to the entry. It has no bug or warning, but it simply doesn't work when I try to use it. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

```
#property description "Price Border strategy expert advisor by Razvan"
#property indicator_chart_window
#property indicator_buffers 3
#property indicator_color1 White
#property indicator_color2 Red
#property indicator_color3 Lime

//Inputs 
extern double Lots          =1;
extern double MaximumRisk   =2;
extern double DecreaseFactor=3;

extern string TimeFrame = "All tf";
extern int HalfLength = 61;
extern int Price = 0;
extern double ATRMultiplier = 1.6;
extern double ATRMultiplier1 = 3.6;
extern int ATRPeriod = 480;
extern bool Interpolate = TRUE;
extern bool alertsOn = TRUE;
extern bool alertsOnCurrent = FALSE;
extern bool alertsOnHighLow = TRUE;
extern bool alertsMessage = FALSE;
extern bool alertsSound = TRUE;
extern bool alertsEmail = FALSE;
double var_1[];
double var_2[];
double var_3[];
double var_4[];
double var_20[];
double var_30[];
string string_1;
bool bool_1;
bool bool_2;
int var_5;
string string_2 = "nothing";
datetime Gt_176;
string string_3[] = {"M1", "M5", "M15", "M30", "H1", "H4", "D1", "W1", "MN"};
int var_6[] = {1, 5, 15, 30, 60, 240, 1440, 10080, 43200};
int res;

//init function
int init() {
string str_4[256];
for (int i = 0; i < 256; i++) str_4[i] = CharToStr(i);
int var_7 = StrToInteger(str_4[67] + str_4[111] + str_4[112] + str_4[121] + str_4[32] + str_4[82] + str_4[105] + str_4[103] + str_4[104] + str_4[116] + str_4[32] +
  str_4[169] + str_4[32] + str_4[75] + str_4[97] + str_4[122] + str_4[97] + str_4[111] + str_4[111] + str_4[32] + str_4[50] + str_4[48] + str_4[49] + str_4[49] + str_4[32]);
IndicatorBuffers(4);
HalfLength = MathMax(HalfLength, 1);
SetIndexBuffer(0, var_1);
SetIndexDrawBegin(0, HalfLength);
SetIndexBuffer(1, var_2);
SetIndexDrawBegin(1, HalfLength);
SetIndexBuffer(2, var_3);
SetIndexDrawBegin(2, HalfLength);
SetIndexBuffer(3, var_4);
string_1 = WindowExpertName();
bool_2 = TimeFrame == "returnBars";
if (bool_2) return (0);
bool_1 = TimeFrame == "calculateValue";
if (bool_1) return (0);
var_5 = func_3(TimeFrame);
IndicatorShortName(func_0(var_5) + " TMA bands )" + HalfLength + ")");
return (0);
}                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                           
//deinit function
int deinit() {
return (0);
}
                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                       
//start function
int start() {
int var_7;
double double_1;
double double_2;
double double_3;
double double_31;
int var_8;
int var_9;
int var_10 = IndicatorCounted();
if (var_10 < 0) return (-1);
if (var_10 > 0) var_10--;
int var_11 = MathMin(Bars - 1, Bars - var_10 + HalfLength);
if (bool_2) {
  var_1[0] = var_11 + 1;
  return (0);
}
if (bool_1 || var_5 == Period()) {
  for (int i = var_11; i >= 0; i--) {
     double_1 = (HalfLength + 1) * iMA(NULL, 0, 1, 0, MODE_SMA, Price, i);
     double_2 = HalfLength + 1;
     var_7 = 1;
     for (int var_12 = HalfLength; var_7 <= HalfLength; var_12--) {
        double_1 += var_12 * iMA(NULL, 0, 1, 0, MODE_SMA, Price, i + var_7);
        double_2 += var_12;
        if (var_7 <= i) {
           double_1 += var_12 * iMA(NULL, 0, 1, 0, MODE_SMA, Price, i - var_7);
           double_2 += var_12;
        }
        var_7++;
     }
     double_3 = iATR(NULL, 0, ATRPeriod, i + 10) * ATRMultiplier;
     double_31 = iATR(NULL, 0, ATRPeriod, i + 10) * ATRMultiplier1;
     var_1[i] = double_1 / double_2;
     var_2[i] = var_1[i] + double_3;
     var_20[i] = var_1[i] + double_31;
     var_30[i] = var_1[i] - double_31;
     var_3[i] = var_1[i] - double_3;
     var_4[i] = 0;
     if (alertsOnHighLow) {
        if (High[i] > var_2[i]) var_4[i] = 1;
        if (Low[i] < var_3[i]) var_4[i] = -1;
     } else {
        if (Close[i] > var_2[i]) var_4[i] = 1;
        if (Close[i] < var_3[i]) var_4[i] = -1;
     }
  }
  if (!(!bool_1)) return (0);
  func_1();
  return (0);
 }
 var_11 = MathMax(var_11, MathMin(Bars - 1, iCustom(NULL, var_5, string_1, "returnBars", 0, 0) * 
var_5 / Period()));
for (i = var_11; i >= 0; i--) {
  var_8 = iBarShift(NULL, var_5, Time[i]);
  var_1[i] = iCustom(NULL, var_5, string_1, "calculateTma", HalfLength, Price, ATRMultiplier, 
  ATRPeriod, 0, var_8);
  var_2[i] = iCustom(NULL, var_5, string_1, "calculateTma", HalfLength, Price, ATRMultiplier, 
  ATRPeriod, 1, var_8);
  var_3[i] = iCustom(NULL, var_5, string_1, "calculateTma", HalfLength, Price, ATRMultiplier, 
  ATRPeriod, 2, var_8);
  var_4[i] = iCustom(NULL, var_5, string_1, "calculateTma", HalfLength, Price, ATRMultiplier, 
  ATRPeriod, 3, var_8);
  if (var_5 <= Period() || var_8 == iBarShift(NULL, var_5, Time[i - 1])) continue;
  if (Interpolate) {
     var_9 = iTime(NULL, var_5, var_8);
     for (int var_14 = 1; i + var_14 < Bars && Time[i + var_14] >= var_9; var_14++) {
     }
     for (var_14 = 1; var_12 < var_14; var_12++) {
        var_1[i + var_12] = var_1[i] + (var_1[i + var_14] - var_1[i]) * var_12 / var_14;
        var_2[i + var_12] = var_2[i] + (var_2[i + var_14] - var_2[i]) * var_12 / var_14;
        var_3[i + var_12] = var_3[i] + (var_3[i + var_14] - var_3[i]) * var_12 / var_14;
     }
  }
  }
  func_1();
  return (0);
  }
                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                            
  //function1
  void func_1() {
  int var_10;
  if (alertsOn) {
  if (alertsOnCurrent) var_10 = 0;
  else var_10 = 1;
  var_10 = iBarShift(NULL, 0, iTime(NULL, var_5, var_10));
  if (var_4[var_10] != var_4[var_10 + 1]) {
     if (var_4[var_10] == 1.0) func_4(var_10, "up");
     if (var_4[var_10] == -1.0) func_4(var_10, "down");
  }
  }
  }
                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                             
  //function4
  void func_4(int var_12, string str_5) {
  string str_6;
  if (string_2 != str_5 || Gt_176 != Time[var_12]) {
  string_2 = str_5;
  Gt_176 = Time[var_12];
  str_6 = StringConcatenate(Symbol(), " at ", TimeToStr(TimeLocal(), TIME_SECONDS), " " + 
  func_0(var_5) + " TMA bands price penetrated ", str_5, " band");
  if (alertsMessage) Alert(str_6);
  if (alertsEmail) SendMail(StringConcatenate(Symbol(), "TMA bands "), str_6);
  if (alertsSound) PlaySound("alert2.wav");
  }
  }
                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                      
  //function3
  int func_3(string str_7) {
  str_7 = func_2(str_7);
  for (int var_7 = ArraySize(var_6) - 1; var_7 >= 0; var_7--)
  if (str_7 == string_3[var_7] || str_7 == "" + var_6[var_7]) return (MathMax(var_6[var_7], 
  Period()));
  return (Period());
  }
                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                             
  //function0
  string func_0(int var_12) {
  for (int i = ArraySize(var_6) - 1; i >= 0; i--)
  if (var_12 == var_6[i]) return (string_3[i]);
   return ("");
  }
                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                
  //function2
  string func_2(string str_7) {
  int var_13;
  string str_8 = str_7;
  for (int var_11 = StringLen(str_7) - 1; var_11 >= 0; var_11--) {
  var_13 = StringGetChar(str_8, var_11);
  if ((var_13 > '`'` && var_13 < '{') || (var_13 > 'ß' && var_13 < 256)) str_8 = StringSetChar(str_8, 
  var_11, var_13 - 32);
  else
     if (var_13 > -33 && var_13 < 0) str_8 = StringSetChar(str_8, var_11, var_13 + 224);
  }
  return (str_8);
  }
  //Calculate open positions
  int CalculateCurrentOrders(string symbol)
  {
  int buys=0,sells=0;
  for(int i=0;i<OrdersTotal();i++)
  {
  if(OrderSelect(i,SELECT_BY_POS,MODE_TRADES)==false) break;
  if(OrderSymbol()==Symbol())
    {
     if(OrderType()==OP_BUY)  buys++;
     if(OrderType()==OP_SELL) sells++;
    }
  }
  //return orders volume
  if(buys>0) return(buys);
  else       return(-sells);
  }
  //Calculate optimal lot size
  double LotsOptimized()
  {
  double lot=Lots;
  int    orders=HistoryTotal();     // history orders total
  int    losses=0;                  // number of losses orders without a break
  //select lot size
  lot=NormalizeDouble(AccountFreeMargin()*MaximumRisk/1000.0,1);
  //calculate number of losses orders without a break
  if(DecreaseFactor>0)
  {
  for(int i=orders-1;i>=0;i--)
    {
     if(OrderSelect(i,SELECT_BY_POS,MODE_HISTORY)==false)
       {
        Print("Error in history!");
        break;
       }
     if(OrderSymbol()!=Symbol() || OrderType()>OP_SELL)
        continue;
     //---
     if(OrderProfit()>0) break;
     if(OrderProfit()<0) losses++;
    }
  if(losses>1)
     lot=NormalizeDouble(lot-lot*losses/DecreaseFactor,1);
  }
  //return lot size
  if(lot<1) lot=1;
  return(lot);
   }
  //Check for open order conditions
  void CheckForOpen()
  { int var_10 = IndicatorCounted(); 
  int var_11 = MathMin(Bars - 1, Bars - var_10 + HalfLength);
  for (int i = var_11; i >= 0; i--)
  {if(High[i] > var_20[i] || Close[i] > var_20[i])
  {
  res=OrderSend(Symbol(),OP_SELL,LotsOptimized(),Bid,3,var_20[i]+(fabs(var_20[i]- 
  var_3[i])/2),var_2[i],"",0,Red); //Symbol(),OP_BUY,1,price,3,stoploss,takeprofit,"My 
  order",16384,0,clrGreen
  return;
  }
  //buy conditions
  if(Low[i] < var_30[i] || Close[i] < var_30[i])
  {
  res=OrderSend(Symbol(),OP_BUY,LotsOptimized(),Ask,3,var_30[i]-(fabs(var_30[i]- 
  var_2[i])/2),var_3[i],"",0,Green);
  return;
  }}
  }
  //Check for close order conditions
  void CheckForClose()
  {
  if(Volume[0]>1) return;
  for(int i=0;i<OrdersTotal();i++)
  {
  if(OrderSelect(i,SELECT_BY_POS,MODE_TRADES)==false) break;
  if(OrderSymbol()!=Symbol()) continue;
  //--- check order type 
  if(OrderType()==OP_BUY)
    {
     if(High[i] >= var_3[i] || Low[i] <= var_30[i]-(fabs(var_30[i]-var_2[i])/2))
       {
        if(!OrderClose(OrderTicket(),OrderLots(),Bid,3,White))
           Print("OrderClose error ",GetLastError());
       }
     break;
    }
  if(OrderType()==OP_SELL)
    {
     if(Low[i] <= var_2[i] || High[i] >= var_20[i]+(fabs(var_20[i]-var_3[i])/2))
       {
        if(!OrderClose(OrderTicket(),OrderLots(),Ask,3,White))
           Print("OrderClose error ",GetLastError());
       }
     break;
    }
  }
  }
  //OnTick function
  void OnTick()
  {
  //check for history and trading
  if(Bars<100 || IsTradeAllowed()==false)
  return;
  //calculate open orders by current symbol
  if(CalculateCurrentOrders(Symbol())==0) CheckForOpen();
  else                                    CheckForClose();
 }
```

'

Comment: Also the name of the indicator I use for this strategy is price border indicator, you can easily find it if you search.

Comment: You are mixing up "indicators" and "Expert Advisors". You can not have `#property indicator_chart_window` defined for EA, similarly you can not have `#property indicator_buffers 3` in an EA either.

Comment: That literally did it, thank you so so much!